# On mouseover do not hide the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two red buttons del-row-td and del-column-td that are shown when I mouseover the blue table and hide when I mouseleave blue table.

[image]

What I need is to stop these red buttons disappear when I move the pointer over them. But make them disappear if I remove pointer both from them and from the blue table.

I am trying to do this via such code:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.del-column-td',function(){
     $(this).removeClass("hide");
   });

$(document).on('mouseleave','.del-column-td',function(){    
   $('.del-column-td').addClass('hide');

});

$(document).on('mouseover','.del-row-td',function(){
     $(this).removeClass("hide");
   });

$(document).on('mouseleave','.del-row-td',function(){   
   $('.del-row-td').addClass('hide');

});
```

Here is the [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mozghovyi/bgfvn8aw/25/). Could anyone suggest ideas why it does not work and how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you've removed the `hide` class, your timer adds it back after a 1s delay:

```
setTimeout(function(){$($('.del-column-td')).addClass('hide');
$($('.del-row-td')).addClass('hide');},1000);
```

(Note that you don't need two `$(` in your code.)

To prevent the behavior you're seeing, assign `setTimeout` to a variable:

```
var timer;
$(document).on('mouseleave','.my-table',function(){ 
   timer = setTimeout(function() {
     $('.del-column-td').addClass('hide');
     $('.del-row-td').addClass('hide');
   }, 1000);  
});
```

Then clear the timer on `mouseover`:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.del-column-td',function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
});

$(document).on('mouseover','.del-row-td',function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqp5Lj2q/)

Comment: thank you, this is almost perfect but I now I can see that I was not precise enough in my description. Is there a way to make so that when I hover over a red button only this button does not disappear but another one - hide? Should I create two timers separately: one for rows and one for columns?

Comment: Two timers may be best.  I've done so at https://jsfiddle.net/gqp5Lj2q/2/